# Adding Contact to InfusionSoft DB Fails using Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, infusionsoft

I'm using the Infusionsoft Ruby API Wrapper. I put

```
gem 'infusionsoft'
```

in my gemfile.

I added my API Key and URL as environmental variables that get loaded into an initializer like so:

```
Infusionsoft.configure do |config|
  config.api_url = ENV['INFUSIONSOFT_URL'] # example infused.infusionsoft.com
  config.api_key = ENV['INFUSIONSOFT_API_KEY']
  config.api_logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/infusionsoft_api.log") # optional logger file
end
```

But when I test the contact add service in my rails console I get this error:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
from /Users/Justus/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

Is anyone aware of a fix for this?

Comment: Are you certain the values are set in `ENV`?

Comment: Need permision from IS first to use the API

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under /root/config/initializers/infusionsoft.rb

```
Infusionsoft.configure do |config|
  config.api_url = 'xyz.infusionsoft.com'
  config.api_key = '6rytrt7c4035aeee7895d2c45fe4595'
  config.api_logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/infusionsoft_api.log") # optional logger file
end
```

Comment: what is xyz in api_url  ?

Comment: your domain name provide by Infusionsoft. See account URL after login

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

while configuring infusionsoft we first need to enable the api key

Reference doc

http://ug.infusionsoft.com/article/AA-00442/0/How-do-I-enable-the-Infusionsoft-API-and-generate-an-API-Key.html